# Can I find out what the IRS knows about me?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, income-tax

Is there a way to get your 'history' or 'profile' form the IRS.  By this I mean, can I find out what has been reported to them about me by third parties over the years in terms of W-4 forms, 1099 forms, etc.?

If I haven't kept good records, can they tell me anything about the returns I've filed over the years?

Answer (score 4):

You can go to the IRS web site and request a transcript or a copy of a return which will give some information.  If you forgot to include income reported on a W2 or 1099 form, you will likely have heard from the IRS already, but if the W2 or 1099 was issued by a small company or individual, it may be some time before the numbers get keyed in to the IRS computers.  Large companies submit these forms electronically to the IRS (with paper copies to the payees) which makes it easier for the IRS to cross-check.

Comment: As I mentioned in [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/14047/5978) I haven't filed a return in years and am looking to get current with the IRS.  What I'd love to have is a list of the different W2s/1099s that have been filed over the years.  That would give me a place to start in filing (and in understanding what I may owe).

Comment: @BackTaxes I again urge you to not try and do this without professional aid. Let the tax accountant figure out what needs to be done and where to start in getting information from the IRS. Yes, you think you might save a little in accountant's fees by getting some information from the IRS yourself and going to the accountant's office with more data, but it could make matters worse and create more issues for the accountant to resolve with the IRS (translation: more fees). Find an accountant and say "Help!" and then do what the accountant says.